# What do the flags SHM_RND of the IPC function shmat mean?

Tags: c, ipc

I checked the man pages, but they don't explain the RND meaning. I want to know the words the RND stand for. Like SHM_RDONLY stand for read-only.thank you!

Comment: strongly suggest making extensive use of the `man` pages for the details about the user available/callable functions.  Note: there is NO `RND` parameter.  The name is `SHM_RND`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means Round, as this [document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg-0.4.pdf)(on page 64) suggests it rounds down to the nearest page size whenever you OR with this flag.

Comment: In C language, the struct aligns its member's address automatically,do you know why IPC don't align the page size automatically,instead offer the flag for the user to choose?

Answer (score 2):

the following is an excerpt from the man page for `shmat()`

If shmaddr isn't NULL and SHM_RND is specified in  shmflg,  the  attach
       occurs at the address equal to shmaddr rounded down to the nearest mul‐
       tiple of SHMLBA.  Otherwise shmaddr must be a page-aligned  address  at
       which the attach occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of this answer, but a simple google search yielded this [1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/basedefs/sys/shm.h.html).